# How to change color of circle temporarily in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to build simon game using html5 canvas and pure javascript. I have managed to get the simon game UI using html5 canvas. My next step is to make the four components light up randomly. I am not sure if this is even possible with html5 canvas or probably my approach is wrong. Any hints in the right direction will be of great help. My code is as follows
codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEdPRN?editors=1010

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//bigger circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(235,230,140,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

//smaller circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(235,230,60,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

//draw the four arcs
var x = [240,240,230,230];
var y = [240,225,225,240];
var start = [0,1.5*Math.PI,1*Math.PI,0.5*Math.PI];
var end = [0.5*Math.PI,0,1.5*Math.PI,1*Math.PI];
var color = ["blue","red","green","yellow"];

var draw = function (a,b,c,d,e) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(a,b,90,c,d);
    ctx.lineWidth = 50;
    ctx.strokeStyle = e;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSimon() {
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    draw(x[i],y[i],start[i],end[i],color[i]);
  }
}

drawSimon();
```

Comment: chose a random color, use requestAnimationFrame for gradual animations or a timer for one-off changes. where are you stuck?

Comment: Am i supposed to re-draw the four components again with the random color? I know one-off changes can be achieved with setInterval but I am not sure how to display the random color once and then revert back to the original color.

Comment: Whenever you change a color in the colors array, call `drawSimon()` again to override the currently displayed image. You might want to clear the canvas with `clearRect(...)` in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem: This is just a static image.

You only call `drawSimon()` once, thus it only gets drawn once. To fix this, you need to use `requestAnimationFrame` or `setInterval` (preferably the first).

`requestAnimationFrame` is like a simple method call, but delays the method, so it lines up with the screen's framerate. You need to call `drawSimon` from inside `drawSimon` with this.

```
function drawSimon() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); //Clear the screen
    //Draw the simon here
    requestAnimationFrame(drawSimon);
}
drawSimon();
```

Next you want to choose a random color and make it lighter. There's a problem with this. Your colors are all already pure colors, you can't make them brighter. You need to use darker colors (example: `rgb(150, 0, 0)` instead of `red`). Then you need to choose a random index between 0 and 3 (inclusively), and make the color in that place brighter.

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        color[0] = "blue";
        break;
    case 1:
        color[0] = "red";
        break;
    case 2:
        color[0] = "green";
        break;
    case 3:
        color[0] = "yellow";
        break;
}
```

Third step: make the colors change back.

You could achieve this with a time counter. Each time you set a color to brighter save the time this was done. Each frame, check the time between the current time and the last time you changed to colors, and if it's over a specific limit, set them back the same way you did with the brighter colors.

```
//global scope:
var lastChange = 0;

//Change a color to lighter here
lastChange = Date.now();

//Later in the code
if (Date.now() - lastChange > maxTime) {
    //Change colors back here
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your detailed response. This sure points me in the right direction.